# Setter for a field in subclass should have the same value validation as that of a different field in super class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, subclass, getter-setter

I want to update the class `Square` by adding the public getter and setter `size`

The setter should assign (in this order) the `width` and the `height` - with the same value
The setter should have the same value validation as the Rectangle for `width` and `height`
No need to change the exception error message (It should be the one from `width`)

The class `Square`  inherits from `Rectangle`.

The setter for `width` in `Rectangle`:

````
    def width(self):
        """
            getter for @__width
        """
        return self.__width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, width):
        """
            validate and set the width attribute
        """
        if width <= 0:
            raise ValueError("width must be > 0")
        if not isinstance(width, int):
            raise TypeError("width must be an integer")
        self.__width = width```

And what i tried to do in ```Square``` for the size attribute:

``` def __init__(self, size, x=0, y=0, id=None):
        """
            Initialise a square with same width and height
        """
        self.__size = size
        super().__init__(self.size, self.size, x, y, id)
    
    @property
    def size(self):
        """
            Getter for size
        """
        return self.__size

    @models.rectangle.Rectangle.width.setter
    def size(self, size):
        """
            Setter for size, using the logic for Rectangle's width
        """
        self.__size = size
````

When I try to assign a value to size I get this error:
`AttributeError: can't set attribute`

*Square is a Rectangle with the same width and height*

Comment: Why don't you just move your "validate code" to another function and then call that function in every setter ?

Comment: Did that, it only works in the rectangle class tough i declared it as a class method. It is not throwing any errors but it seems like it is being skipped. The value for size entered during first initialisation persists even if i try updating e.g:  `s = Square(5)` works. When i try `s.size = 10`, the size remains 5. Also, assigning a string works though the validation code must throw a TypeError

Comment: Ok, I guess you got a bug somewhere :),  so.... I give you some code that works and it has validation and setter in one function.

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is public, so you can do something like this:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width):
        self.__width = width

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.__width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, width):
        self.setter(Rectangle.__name__, width=width)

    def setter(self, class_name, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if v <= 0:
                raise ValueError(f"{k} must be > 0")
            if not isinstance(v, int):
                raise TypeError(f"{k} must be an integer")
            self.__setattr__(f"_{class_name}__" + k, v)

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, size, x=0, y=0, id=None):
        self.__size = size
        super().__init__(self.__size)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self.__size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, size):
        self.setter(Square.__name__, size=size)


s = Square(1)
print("After __init__")
print(s.__dict__)
s.width = 5
s.size = 3
print("After setter")
print(s.__dict__)
print(s.size, s.width)
```

Output:

```
After __init__
{'_Square__size': 1, '_Rectangle__width': 1}
After setter
{'_Square__size': 3, '_Rectangle__width': 5}
3 5
```